# Using a UserForm to Populate Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I would like the users of this file to copy a list of what we call "family codes" into a UserForm and then when they click a button on the UserForm, this list of family codes will populate a column in Excel. See below for exactly what I envision. Mostly, I just can't find a specific UserForm that can handle this, but I welcome any better ways to do this as well.

Example of "family codes": AS10, AS08, AS06, B137 -- These are always four digit letter/number combinations

**Step 1:**
User takes a list such as this that they want to use in the file:

- AS10
- AS08
- AS06

They would copy these family codes vertically, as they are stored in separate rows in excel (ex. they would copy these families out of cells "A2:A4".

**Step 2:** The user pastes the vertical data into a UserForm

**Step 3:** The user clicks a command button on the userform and a macro pastes these families into cells "D2:D4" in vertical order in separate rows.

[image: Steps]

Comment: "Mostly, I just can't find a specific UserForm that can handle this" - have you tried to build it yourself?

Comment: @BigBen No I have not. That's something I might have to look into doing.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I feel like an idiot... All I needed to do was change the "MultiLine" setting of the TextBox to true instead of false. Now I can paste in vertical data and pull it out.

Only hope is someone else with the same issue might discover my question before spending too much time!